# What is the Illuminati?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Usually when someone says something weird or random, someone says ¨Illuminati confirmed!¨ (Or they do at my school:). I know that the Illuminati was a group that disbanded over 100 years ago, but why do people use the term now?

Comment: It's from conspiracy theorists, like this guy: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_William_Cooper I don't know how exactly the idea became generally known; I think some rappers referenced his work in their lyrics.

Comment: I never heard of Milton William Cooper, but I remember reading [Robert Anton Wilson's *Illuminatus! Trilogy* trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57913.The_Illuminatus_Trilogy) back in the early 80s. And there's [Illuminati detected!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4_0UKb-cdI) on Youtube, but with only 37 views (with just one "like") as I write, you could hardly say the concept has gone viral.

Comment: It has gone viral I've traveled to many different schools and have heard the phrase Illuminati Confirmed many different times. I hear it everywhere I turn...no matter which school I attend

Answer (score 1):

"The Illuminati" is a phrase that's come into common usage, particularly with the conspiratorial crowd, to refer to a shadowy group of elite, who rule from "behind the curtain" or even are co-involved with aliens.

The phrase you refer to "Illuminati confirmed!" would be a tongue-in-cheek humorous reference to this, meant to both deride and ridicule the conspiracy theorists AND express wonder at the synchronicity of it all, in one fell swoop!

Answer (score 0):

First, as long as I pointed out, in order for your friends to say this, they must be part of a very niche subculture. This also structures the context and meaning.

Illuminati were a group of people that deep and broad knowledge of what usual topics. Could be argued that their strength, as a group, was based in the way that they utilize this is so Terric information to derive expert plans. (Competency)

The mainstream opinion of the illuminati and their knowledge is one of skepticism regarding this unusual information. The skepticism may be drawn from uncertainty regarding how this information is applied, particularly considering that it was generally applied in secret. Associate this with the fact that any random person may know a few oddball things, but not do anything 'productive' with them.

When people are using the expression you mentioned, they are lightheartedly indicating that the target is aware of strange and unusual knowledge. Implicitly they often also suggest that such knowledge is not practical and only for lighthearted ends.

Comment: No, but I have engineer something